# Bing Map: Issue with directions manager drag and drop -

Tags: bing-maps, directions

I am currently working on bing map's directions manager. I am creating a trip/route by adding few waypoints. After getting a result from the directionsManager, if i drag and drop a waypoint(marker on the map), I am facing an inconsistency issue with bing map's direction manager. I do not get the address of the waypoint back from the directionsManager.getAllWaypoints().

Issue: i do not get the address after drag and drop always (I do get it most of the times but there are instances wheen i dont get it as well); however i do get the lat long of that wypoint. 
I am checking for the updated address in the event handler 'directionsUpdated', using directionsManager.getAllwaypoints(). i have tried event 'dragDropCompleted' that also doesn't help.

Observation:
* 'directionsUpdated' occurs after 'dragDropCompleted'.
* I do see the address after the complete map is loaded, but i need it before that.

I am using ajax api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not very clear what your issue is and what you are trying to achieve. By the sounds of it you are trying to drag a pushpin and get the address it is on. If that's what you want you can do this without the directions manager.

Comment: Hi @rbrundritt, apologies about the confusion and for the delay in my response. Yes, i am trying to get the address from a dragged and dropped marker on the map, in a trip/route.I am not very familiar how i can use pushpin. can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to drag a pushpin on a map and get the address it was dropped on you can do this fairly easily. Here is an example of how to make a pushpin draggable and fire an event when it is dropped: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins13

Once you have this you can either use the Search Module in the Bing Maps control or the Bing Maps REST services to reverse geocode the coordinate the pushpin is dropped on. Here are some examples of how to do the reverse geocoding:

https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#SearchModule3

https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#RESTServices1

For the second example set the query value to "[latitude],[longitude]", make sure to replace the square brackets with the actual numbers.